# What is the difference between "deshalb", "darum", "deswegen", "aus diesem Grund", "daher" in a German sentence?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

Please identify exactly what is the difference between these words in the German language.

As I know, these words get used when we have some consequences after the first sentence. I read some about them but I can not discern them from each other.

Please tell me the meaning of the related sentence below in English also:

> Jennifer hat kurz vor dem Essen vom Tod ihres Onkels erfahren. (Deshalb/Darum/Deswegen/Aus diesem Grund/Daher) hat sie das Essen abgesagt.

Comment: I would say, there is no difference.

Comment: Too broad and covered by various existing questions: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/warum-darum-weshalb-deshalb-weswegen-deswegen-is-there-a-difference-in, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24405/sind-deshalb-und-daher-austauschbar, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/what-is-the-difference-between-somit-and-deshalb

Comment: @Iris could you please  tell me the meaning of that sentence in English

Comment: Asking for translations is off topic.

Comment: @chirlu that is related to the topic as I mentioned the words.

Comment: @chirlu about the existing questions, the first and third link are related but talking about something else and the second link is all in German

Comment: The first link is exactly about this, albeit only a subset of the too many words you ask about. The third link is about another similar word.

Comment: @chirlu it is in your opinion but not mine, don't argue with me

Comment: Du möchtest 10 paarweise Vergleiche?

Comment: @userunknown Nein, Ich möchte nur den unterschied zwischen ihnen

Comment: Bei 5 Begriffen kommt man aber auf 10 Paare, für die man Unterschiede suchen kann. ab ac ad ae bc bd be cd ce de.

Comment: @userunknown when learning a new language there might be even one word annoying you. I wanted to clarify and make it clear for myself. It does not matter what you think about my question and already existing answers. what's the matter is that my complete answer is here and I'm happy that I got it right. you better come back with your main account not with your fake one.

Comment: @Mehdi: By acting in an aggressive way and making unfounded accusations, you run the risk to get banned.

Comment: @Mehdi: Was verstehst Du unter meinem Mainaccount?

Comment: Das sind Synonyme. Das bedeutet alles dasselbe.

Comment: @user unknown: Ich denke, er meinte damit meinen.

Comment: @chirlu: Du meinst, er meint, dass einer von uns die Sockenpuppe des anderen sei? Das ist zumindest originell! :) (Moment, ich melde mich kurz ab, um mich neu anzumelden, um mir zu antworten).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference if you don't have an interrogative adverb ("Fragewort").

The interrogative adverbs for each are:

- Weshalb? / Deshalb!

  > Weshalb hat Jennifer das Essen abgesagt?
  >   Jennifer hat kurz vor dem Essen vom Tod ihres Onkels erfahren. Deshalb hat sie das Essen abgesagt.
- Warum? / Darum!

  > Warum hat Jennifer das Essen abgesagt?
  >   Jennifer hat kurz vor dem Essen vom Tod ihres Onkels erfahren. Darum hat sie das Essen abgesagt.
- Weswegen? /Deswegen!

  > Weswegen hat Jennifer das Essen abgesagt?
  >   Jennifer hat kurz vor dem Essen vom Tod ihres Onkels erfahren. Deswegen hat sie das Essen abgesagt.

Here you have to change it up a bit to make it fit.

- Woher?/ Daher!

  > Woher kommt die Enscheidung Jennifers das Essen abzusagen?
  >   Jennifer hat kurz vor dem Essen vom Tod ihres Onkels erfahren. Daher kommt die Entscheidung das Essen abzusagen.

The translation of the Sentence is:

> Jennifer was told of her uncel's death shortly before the meal. So she canceled the meal.

Comment: this -> Jennifer hat kurz vor dem Essen vom Tod ihres Onkels erfahren. (Deshalb/Darum/Deswegen/Aus diesem Grund/Daher) hat sie das Essen abgesagt.
please add to your answer because I mentioned it in my question

Comment: Auf eine Weshalbfrage kann/darf/soll man also nicht mit Daher oder Darum antworten?